# Tensorflow 2.4 doesn't work despite my cpu having AVX support

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS/tf version 2.4.0, and I am not able to run the tensorflow library, because it always results in an error

This is the only line that I put in 
`import tensorflow as tf`

This is the error it gives out 
`Illegal instruction (core dumped)`

These are the processor specs

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 58
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3437U CPU @ 1.90GHz
stepping    : 9
microcode   : 0x21
cpu MHz     : 842.451
cache size  : 3072 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cpuid_fault epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit srbds
bogomips    : 4789.04
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

If more information will be needed I will provide it.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, it started yesterday. Are you using wsl2?

Comment: You should be able to inspect the core dump with a debugger and see what instruction was illegal.  That should help indicate what CPU features it's trying to use which you don't have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem running the tf version 2.4.0 in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS. I have been looking for a solution but I didn't find it yet so, for now, I am using the previous version which works for me.

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow==2.3.1
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be fixed now in 2.4.1